# HQL is filtering out fields with null

Tags: hibernate

In one table I have:

| oid | code_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

code name is foreign key on second table:

| oid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BANANA |
| 2 | APPLE |
| 3 | ORANGE |

My HQL is:

```
FROM table1 o ORDER BY o.code_name.name
```

but for some reason the result I got when I do the sort is sorted table without the null row.

| oid | code_name | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | APPLE |
| 1 | 1 | BANANA |
| 4 | 3 | ORANGE |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put `ORDER BY o.code_name.name` it means that you have to join the other table. Seem like Hibernate transform this `HQL` to `INNER JOIN` in plain `SQL`.

You have to put `LEFT JOIN` manually.

```sql
SELECT t1 FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN t1.code_name t2 
ORDER BY t2.name
```

Comment: I can configure it in the objects.hbm.xml? when I'm defining the structure?